# diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, cocoapods

am new to the iPhone app development.when i an running the application i getting the Bellow error.

diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: Are you familiar with using Cocoapods? Is this your own project or is this from an application you've downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: yes i was download  the application somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message shows the solution, no pods are built.
Open the terminal, go to the root of the project, then run:

```
pod install
```

If you don't have cocoapods installed, first run

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then repeat the previous command

Comment: In my case i have done this 'pod install' thing but didn't work.

Comment: This did not work for me. Tried all the solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797068/diff-podfile-lock-no-such-file-or-directory-react-native-xcode

Answer (score 1):

Include xcconfig files from Pods project inside the xcconfig files for the main project solved this issue.

1. Use "Open Quickly" in Xcode and type in "*release.xcconfig*",
2. two results can show up, the Pods project corespondant can easily be identified with the prefix "*Pods*"
3. include the "Pods-xyz.release.xcconfig" into the realease.xcconfig for the main project.
4. Do the above steps for "*debug.xcconfig*".