# /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory - no solutions working?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

Ok, I have looked at nearly every other question relating to this problem [Xcode /Podfile.lock: No such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769333/xcode-podfile-lock-no-such-file) and [diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696463/diff-podfile-lock-no-such-file-or-directory)

NONE of these solutions are working for me. In 1 project only, I get these errors:

[image]

What I have done/tried:

1. pod deintegrate
2. deleted the pod file and pod folder
3. clean xcode
4. tried again fresh with pod init
5. pod install
6. clean Xcode

I have also done

1. sudo gem install cocoapods
2. pod install
3. clean again

What is wrong here? Why is it just this project?

EDIT:

terminal error:

```
[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `11.0` on target `LittleBot` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `LittleBot` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-LittleBot/Pods-LittleBot.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-LittleBot/Pods-LittleBot.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Configuration/SampleCode.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `LittleBot` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-LittleBot/Pods-LittleBot.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-LittleBot/Pods-LittleBot.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Configuration/SampleCode.xcconfig`).
```

Configuration/SampleCode.xcconfig:

//
//  SampleCode.xcconfig
//

```
// The `SAMPLE_CODE_DISAMBIGUATOR` configuration is to make it easier to build
// and run a sample code project. Once you set your project's development team,
// you'll have a unique bundle identifier. This is because the bundle identifier
// is derived based on the 'SAMPLE_CODE_DISAMBIGUATOR' value. Do not use this
// approach in your own projects—it's only useful for sample code projects because
// they are frequently downloaded and don't have a development team set.
SAMPLE_CODE_DISAMBIGUATOR=${DEVELOPMENT_TEAM}
```

Comment: Couple more suggestions: restart Xcode, remove DerivedData, reboot, ...

Comment: No warning or error while pod install?

Comment: @Ryan ah.. I may have found something. Now posting my error above - it says something in terminal as a warning that I need to include pods in my config file. But I don't know what is really meant by that

Comment: Can you show your `Podfile`?

Comment: I don't have any pods - But my project as a whole was an example file originally ill post the config file

Comment: Ah. Never mind this was the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287103/cocoapods-warning-cocoapods-did-not-set-the-base-configuration-of-your-project