# diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory - React Native - Xcode

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am working on existing React-native project for iOS. I have followed the initial instructions from [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and demo app is working fine.

But in existing project there is podfile. So in that project I have ran `pod install` successfully.
Then when I open `myIOSApp.xcworkspace` in XCode and run Project Build. The build got failed with 3 errors:

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

The folder in which the `myIOSApp.xcworkspace` exists, also has Podfile and Podfile.lock. I have tried almost all solution but this error is not going.

If I run `react-native run-ios`, it opens iPhone simulator, but terminal exited with errors like:

```
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.



Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myIOSApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I have tried several solutions, like: closing XCode, and then running `pod install`, or Clearing Project Build from `Product` menu, and rebuilding it. Or `gem install cocoapods` or `pod deintegrate`. Or deleting and `Xcode/DerivedData` folder.

**EDIT 1**
Somehow `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH` & `PODS_ROOTS` values were missing in `User defined setting` in Target > Build Setting. I don't know why it was not set by default.
After this i am getting only 1 error:
`lexical or preprocessor issue file not found`, throwing this error for lib that was installed by `pod install`. Something like `libname.h` file is not found.

But no luck. Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

The error is gone.

Check **Edit 1** in question. `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH` & `PODS_ROOT`variables were missing in User defined Build setting.

And also I was using different `Pod` version. So I've installed Pod version `1.6.1`, the version that other developer used. And after that, all the above variable got set correctly. And build created successfully. So it was `cocoapods` version issue.